# PNG doesn't have white background in GIMP

Tags: gimp, png

I am attempting to create a PNG with a white background in Gimp. Here is the result:

> [image: Result Image (transparent, not white)]

How can I fix this so that the images is grey on white?

Comment: So you do not want a transparent background and instead want a white background?

Comment: @AndrewH Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Channel Dialog which is under the Layer Dialog. Delete the Alpha channel. It is added there by default.